# How to extract ROS non-detects value and match them to their original row using sample ID in R?

Tags: r

I am analysing a database with over 300 values.

For this question I read in 20 samples under the name **r**. The following code was used to prepare the dataset for ROS analysis to handle non-detected values.

1. NAs were removed
2. Non-detects identified (values with < in exposure)
3. New variable exposure2 created for the statistical analysis.

````
r$nd[!is.na(r$exposure)]<-grepl("<", r$exposure) #True=non-detect False=true concentration


  r$exposure2<-r$exposure #exposure2 is used to run analysis to ensure ROS is correct
  r$exposure2<-(gsub('<', '', r$exposure))
  r$exposure2<-as.numeric(r$exposure2)

  r<-r[!is.na(r$exposure),]
```
`

   id         job exposure     type    nd exposure2
1   1      driver     0.10     area FALSE      0.10
2   2     cleaner     0.09 personal FALSE      0.09
3   3    mechanic     0.24 personal FALSE      0.24
4   4 electrician     0.11     area FALSE      0.11
5   5         CSA    <0.05 personal  TRUE      0.05
6   6    security     0.05 personal FALSE      0.05
7   7      driver     0.08     area FALSE      0.08
8   8         CSA     0.12 personal FALSE      0.12
9   9      driver    <0.04 personal  TRUE      0.04
10 10      driver    <0.02     area  TRUE      0.02
12 12    mechanic    <0.10 personal FALSE      0.10
14 14         CSA     0.24 personal  TRUE      0.24
15 15         CSA     0.11 personal FALSE      0.11
16 16      driver    <0.05 personal FALSE      0.05
17 17    security    <0.05 personal FALSE      0.05
18 18      driver    <0.02     area  TRUE      0.02
20 20      driver     0.10 personal  TRUE      0.10

The following code was used to run ROS successfully. 

``
library(NADA)
myros = ros(r$exposure2, r$nd) *#I could not introduce sample ID here*
plot(myros)
summary(myros)
mean(myros); sd(myros)
quantile(myros); median(myros)
print(as.data.frame(myros))
``


These are the results of myros.

    obs censored        pp    modeled
1  0.02     TRUE 0.0929557 0.02831973
2  0.02     TRUE 0.1859114 0.03726359
3  0.04     TRUE 0.1394336 0.03300924
4  0.05     TRUE 0.1394336 0.03300924
5  0.05    FALSE 0.3369644 0.05000000
6  0.05    FALSE 0.3950617 0.05000000
7  0.05    FALSE 0.4531590 0.05000000
8  0.08    FALSE 0.5112564 0.08000000
9  0.09    FALSE 0.5693537 0.09000000
10 0.10    FALSE 0.6797386 0.10000000
11 0.10    FALSE 0.7320261 0.10000000
12 0.10     TRUE 0.3137255 0.04834912
13 0.11    FALSE 0.7843137 0.11000000
14 0.11    FALSE 0.8366013 0.11000000
15 0.12    FALSE 0.8888889 0.12000000
16 0.24    FALSE 0.9705882 0.24000000
17 0.24     TRUE 0.4705882 0.06288412

I want to extract these back into the dataframe **r**. However, when I do so there is no way to match them using the sample ID. 

```
`r$exposure3<-as.data.frame(myros)
`
```
Please advise how I can run the ros functions with sample ID built in and then how do I insert the results by matching using this sample ID. 

The final result will have columns from both dataframes. The trick is how to run the ROS code with sample ID in order to use it to match when combining the dataframes. 

*id job exposure type  nd exposure2   obs   censored  pp  modeled*
````

Comment: @Ben I have edited my query to show the final output. To clarify further, when ROS functions are run they do not take into account sample ID, and part of ROS is reordering the original values. So conceptually I need to find a way to run ROS taking into account sample ID, and having it move with its original value. After that it is easy to match the dataframes using the sample ID variable.

Comment: That is not possible. The ros is built to do the ordering within the package. I took a course from the guy that built the NADA package. My idea was to figure out how to input the Sample ID into the ros function but anything added within the function renders it useless. And the exposure values can be repetitive so I could not match using them.